# Real time calendar needs new instance?

Tags: android, calendar

Should t & t1 be equal?

```
if (calendar==null)
    calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
int t = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
try {
    Thread.sleep(3333);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int t1 = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, t and t1 should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you have tried to print out the values both `t & t1` will be always equal.